# What 新派-Cantonese Habits Are Considered Unorthodox By 老派 Speakers?

Tags: cantonese

新派 topolect speakers are generally more affected by MSM. This often results in a lot of habits that are considered unorthodox by 老派 dialect speakers' standards.

I'm not overly familiar with Cantonese but I'm curious to know what 新派 habits are looked down upon by 老派 speakers?

A few possibilities:

- the introduction of 懒音, e.g.: the dropping of initial /ŋ-/
- replacement of topolectical vocabulary with that of MSM
- tonal changes defaulting to MSM instead of topolectical pronunciations

Aside from the /ŋ/ ---> /∅/ switch, my speculations are all quite broad and vague.

Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127475/discussion-on-question-by-mou-what--cantonese-habits-are-considered-unorthodo).

Answer (score 2):

Other than the one you mentioned, the only predominant one I am aware of would be `n` replaced by `l` when it's the first sound of a character. Very common in young speakers but generally expected to make an effort to use the proper `n` sound when speaking to elders or formally.